# How to tail Whenever logs from a Dokku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever, dokku

I'm using [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in my rails app running on Dokku.

I know the way to tail the app's logs is `dokku logs appname -t`

I know Whenever has a way to [define where the logs should be written](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs)

However, it's unclear how one should specify a log file when running `dokku logs`, or tell Whenever to use a log file that's handled by dokku.

Has anyone run into the same issue before?

Answer (score 2):

I had some troubles trying to run dokku + whenever.

What I finished doing was using [crono](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) instead of wherenever.

From documentation:

> Currently, there is no such thing as Ruby Cron for Rails. Well,
>   there's Whenever but it works on top of Unix Cron, so you can't manage
>   it from Ruby. Crono is pure Ruby. It doesn't use Unix Cron and other
>   platform-dependent things. So you can use it on all platforms
>   supported by Ruby. It persists job states to your database using
>   Active Record. You have full control of jobs performing process. It's
>   Ruby, so you can understand and modify it to fit your needs.

With crono, instead of having a `schedule.rb` file:

```
every 5.seconds do
  rake 'crono:hello'
end
```

you have a `cronotab.rb` file:

```
# config/cronotab.rb
require 'rake'

Rails.app_class.load_tasks

class Test
  def perform
    Rake::Task['crono:hello'].invoke
  end
end

Crono.perform(Test).every 5.seconds
```

**How to run in dokku?**

Simple add in your proc file:

```
crono: bundle exec crono
```

Then

```
ps:scale <app> crono=1
```

And your scheduling tasks will run smoothly in your dokku container.